# I'm working on an Ionic project(moodle app -v4.0.2) and while building for the project for android I,m getting error

Tags: ionic-framework, methods, compilation, find

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/hussain/testing/moodleapp-4.0.2/platforms/android/cordova-plugin-badge/moodlemobile-badge.gradle' line: 28
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I,m lookin for the solution but what I came to know is that I would have replace compile with implentation.
But while building again the platforms/gradle files will again generate and will have to edit again and again